# Why a message handler doesn't work in debugging mode?

Tags: delphi

I use berlin in windows 10.

The following message handler works well in a built application but doesn't in debugging mode.

How can I debug the message handler?

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure onReceive(var message: TMessage); message WM_COPYDATA;
  end;

procedure TForm1.onReceive(var message: TMessage);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('a');
end;
```

The sender code is as follows and the value of the struct is meaningless.

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  _Handle: Cardinal;
  _CopyDataStruct: TCopyDataStruct;
begin
  _Handle := FindWindow(nil, 'test form');

  _CopyDataStruct.dwData := 0;
  _CopyDataStruct.cbData := Sizeof(_Handle);
  _CopyDataStruct.lpData := @_handle;

  SendMessage(_Handle, WM_COPYDATA, Handle, integer(@_CopyDataStruct));
end;
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `Memo1.Lines.Add('a')`, and then run. Then run your other app that sends the WM_COPYDATA message to your first app.

Comment: My guess would be the message never arrives, the sending party is targeting the window in the designer.

Comment: Your debugger runs elevated?

Comment: @KenWhite the breakpoint doesn't stop the process. thanks.

Comment: Then either the message isn't being sent, or it's being sent to the wrong window.

Comment: @KenWhite i guess so too but it works well in a built application as i mentioned above. i can't recognize the difference of situations. thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting `@_Handle` as the `lpData` to send? A `Cardinal` is only 4 bytes in size, not 10 bytes. You are sending data that belongs to the call stack, 6 bytes of which are surrounding the `_Handle` variable in memory. This is a bad recipe for disaster.

Comment: The difference is that the IDE (debugger) is between your application and the sender of the message.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes i does indeed. i'm sorry that i can't understand the meaning of targeting the window in the designer. i got the handle with the caption which is 'test form'. thanks.

Comment: @JOSeongGng: yes, but there are **multiple windows** running with the **same** caption - one in your app, one in the IDE designer. Your code is not differentiating between them, so it is likely sending to the wrong one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it was just a meaningless value and i fixed it. but the result is same. thanks.

Comment: @JOSeongGng: The result is the same because you are still not taking the IDE designer into account in your window searching.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes. the ide runs as the administrative elevation. thanks.

Comment: @JOSeongGng: UIPI prevents a lower-integrity process from sending window messages to the windows of a higher-integrity (ie elevated) process, unless the higher-integrity process calls `ChangeMessageFilter/Ex()` on itself to allow lower-integrity processes to send specific window messages through the UIPI filter.

Comment: Stop running your debugger elevated. It causes you pain.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan when i run the delphi with non administrative elevation it works well. thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - and possibly causes your users pain as you make a mistake, then your app requires elevation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your `TForm1` class is open in the IDE's Form Designer, and its `Caption` is `test form` in the Object Inspector, then the `FindWindow()` is likely finding *that* `HWND` at runtime instead of the `HWND` that is inside your running app (you can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to verify that).  Which means you would be sending your message to the wrong `HWND`.  This is a common problem when using `FindWindow()` to search for a `TForm` by its caption while running in the debugger.  Close the `TForm1` source file in the IDE, and then `FindWindow()` won't be able to find that `HWND` anymore, it will find the `HWND` in your running app instead.

And BTW, your `_Handle` variable needs to be declared as `HWND` or `THandle` instead of `Cardinal`, and the last parameter of `SendMessage()` needs to be type-cast to `LPARAM` instead of `integer`.

Comment: Looking at the comments it seems that the issue for the asker is that the ide was run elevated

Comment: That does not affect an app's ability to **send** messages, only **receive them**.. I still think the issue has to do with the app trying to send to the designer window. If the IDE were running elevated, and `FindWindow()` were finding the designer window, then UIPI would apply, though it wouldn't really matter since the designer is the wrong target anyway. Making the IDE run unelevated would simply remove UIPI, which would only matter if the debugged app is the receiver, not the sender. I suspect the zorder is simply different, causing `FindWindow()` to find a different window.

Comment: Failure to receive would explain things. Asker commented that running IDE non elevated resolved the problem. Code in the question shows both sending and receiving.

Comment: If the IDE is running elevated, any application run from it will also elevated. Elevated apps can "see" all other elevated apps and in many cases "see" non-elevated apps.